# Проблема с подключением к PostgresSQL (telebot)

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot, telebot

Здраствуйте, возникла проблема к подключению  к БД(на HEROKU).

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bot.py", line 28, in <module>
     conn = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "ec2-52-6-75-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (52.6.75.198) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 46648?
```

Код:

```
database = os.environ.get('DATABASE')
user = os.environ.get('USER')
password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
host = os.environ.get('HOST')
port = os.environ.get('PORT')

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database = f"{database}", 
    user = f"{user}", 
    password = f"{password}", 
    host = f"{host}", 
    port = f"{port}"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['request', 'Запрос', 'запрос'])
def send_request(message):
    try:
        
        user_id = message.from_user.id

        cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id FROM public."main_BD" WHERE user_id = \'{user_id}\';')
        userinbd = cursor.fetchone()
        conn.commit()

        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Yes', callback_data = 'yes')
        item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'No', callback_data = 'no')
        markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
        
        if message.chat.id != -1001366701849 and userinbd[0] is None:
            delete = bot.send_message(-1001366701849, 'Welcome')
            Timer(600, check).start()

            cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO public."main_BD"(user_id) VALUES (\'{user_id}\');')
            conn.commit()
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'No!!!')
    
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(618042376, f'Ошибка в send_request: {e}')
```

Файл `settings.py`

```
import dj_database_url
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode = 'require')
DATABASE_URL['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age = 600, ssl_require = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно помню, для Хероку постгре, кроме основных параметров типа user, host и тд нужно также передать HEROKU_CLI, который находится все в тех же Database Credentials на сайте хероку

```
HEROKU_CLI = os.getenv('HEROKU_CLI')
```

А порт точно 46648, не 5432?

Comment: Да, написано что порт 5432.

Comment: `HEROKU_CLI = os.getenv('HEROKU_CLI')` куда эту строку надо вставить? В `settings.py`?